# Are daemon threads killed when main thread calls sys.exit()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

According to the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

> A thread can be flagged as a “daemon thread”. The significance of this flag is that the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads are left. The initial value is inherited from the creating thread. The flag can be set through the daemon property or the daemon constructor argument.

Sample code:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=MultiHandler().network, args=(conn, data), daemon=True)
thread.start()
```

Refering to many other StackOverflow answers, it is not clear to me if daemon threads are forced to close when the main thread calls `sys.exit()`

Comment: When a program exits, all of its children threads are killed with it. Threads that are not _daemonic_ will prevent the program from exiting, hence preventing their own destruction.

Comment: @zwer In that case if my threads are non-daemon do I still have to call `join()` to wait for the thread before calling `sys.exit()`?

Comment: You don't, but then you lose control over your program exit. If you don't manage graceful exit you'll end up with your main thread _finishing_ and then hanging there waiting for other threads to finish with no way to instigate that.

Comment: Documentation for `sys.exit()` is less than clear about multi-threaded programs, but if you look closely, you'll see that it says that `sys.exit()` doesn't do anything but throw an exception.  So, it will only terminate the one thread that calls it, and only if the thread has no handler that swallows the exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to the comment posted by zwer,

> When a program exits, all of its children threads are killed with it. Threads that are not daemonic will prevent the program from exiting, hence preventing their own destruction. - zwer

In short, yes daemon threads will not stop the program from exiting thus they will be killed on exit.